# Joomla Component Install Issue: Can't install any components, fresh install of latest Joomla

Tags: joomla

When I try to install any component, specifically my mtwMigrator component, I receive the following error:

```
    * Warning! Failed to move file.
```

This is on a fresh install, with FTP Layer turned off, with default content installed, Joomla 1.5.14, latest PHP and my_SQL versions, Legacy mode turned on.

Answer (score 1):

A very common cause of this error is due to file permissions. Joomla must be able to copy the files from your component into the `components` and `administrator/components` directories. If the system user the webserver runs as does not have write permissions to these folders, it will not be able to copy the files over.

The FTP layer is there to get around this issue. With the FTP layer on, you upload the component to the server first, then it is FTP'ed from the temporary directory to `localhost`. For this to work, the FTP user you specify must have permission to write to the `components` and `administrator/components` folders.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to set the right perms for the folders, and bypass the step of me setting up FTP Layer?

IF so, where can I find a list of what perms these folders should be set to?

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Please DON'T set your folders to 777, this is INSECURE! Very frequently, your server will run as the `apache` or `nobody` user. Some hosts will configure the server in such a way that files are copied under your username instead. If your server is not set up this way, use the FTP layer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when moving between machines (I know you said it was a fresh install - but someone might find this helpful). Ensure the $tmp_path entry in joomla\configuration.php is pointing to a valid directory. Mine wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

In your Joomla backend, on the top menu, go to Help >> System Info >> Directory Permission and ensure that that are writable otherwise you don't want to have to change the folders to 777 and back again each time you install an extension.

In addition to this, you can mass chmod folders and files using [Akeeba Admin Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087).
You mgiht also want to update to the latest Joomla 1.5 version (1.5.26)

Comment: This work form me! thanks. But is in Control panel > System Info > Directory Permission

Comment: @PabloMartinez - For Joomla 2.5+ yes, you're right, but as you can see in the OP is using Joomla 1.5 ;)

Comment: I have 1.5 also... :P and in Help >> System Info >> Directory Permission tells You have to go to Control panel

Comment: @PabloMartinez - It's not in the Control Panel. It's like I said lol. [See this image](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ZzpftMOvPJg/Ta1xdKrUh3I/AAAAAAAABXE/iI_Iss8Xaao/s1600/joomla_system_info.png)

Answer (score 1):

The most ideal permission for Joomla directories is 755. There are cases when mod_suphp is not installed that the permission problem would occur. 
Make sure that mod_suphp is installed and loaded by checking your php info e.g.  and running this on your browser. If mod_suphp is not installed, then you will need help from your hosting provider to install this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, all directerories should have 755 (rwxr-xr-x) and all files 644 (rw-r--r--). If you want to set the most directories to not-writetable, you will need at least the directories listed in Help > System info > Directory Permissions. (Here you can also check which directories need to be changed, as non-writetable directories are shown in red.)

In some shared hosting environments, 755  / 644 isn't enough, as the owner of the file is not the (Web)Server User, but the FTP-User ... so either change it to 777 / 666 (not recommended, as you allow others to write your files), or get your FTP layer to work.

Another try: Joomla! does not work yet with the recent PHP 5.3. Can you use PHP 5.2? ([Similar Problem in the Joomla Forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=199&t=417159))

Comment: hmmm. I set my entire folder dirs to 777 and now my component is able to upload. I guess I should set them back to 755 when I'm finished working on the site?

Comment: yes set it back to 755 (folders) and 644(files) once you have finished installing the component ;)